# hide hyperlink text of anchor <a> tag in browser status bar but it should navigate

Tags: hyperlink, redirect

1. I have a referral project.

   2. In that there is an *agent* between the
      *affiliate*(my site) and the *target site*.
   3. So all hyperlinks displayed in my
      site will be redirected to the *agents*
      site and then it is redirected to the
      *target* site.
   4. The hyperlink itself is the link to
      the *agents* site.
   5. So i am displaying all products. I
      have given links to them. When users
      hover a hyeprlink you can see the
      href text displayed in the status bar
      which will be the *agents* site.
   6. The requirement is the hyperlinks of
      an *agent* site should not be displayed
      in the status bar.

**My solutions and assumptions**

7. So i can use span onclick =
   window.location = hrefOfAgentLink.
8. I have seen in other sites that they
   redirect to another scripting page
   and then the redirection takes
   place. for example
   http://sitename.com/click/id=32.
9. The id refers to the hyperlink in
   database. hope they fetch the link
   and they do a location header to
   redirect to the *agent* page.

Why so? because the user should not see where the link goes.

**I want to know whether there is(are) any other option(s) so that the hyperlink will not be visible in the status bar and in the address bar when it is redirecting.**

Anyway when redirecting the *agents* url is not visible because it immediately redirects to the *target* site.

I would like to have the stackoverflow users suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you keep having to make excuses about the legitimacy of this scheme?

Comment: Just thought of mentioning that.

Comment: "the user should not see where the link goes." It's how the internet works. Trying to bypass it is just plain wrong. If you want to, explain to your users that they'll be redirected through another site, and let them decide whether they want to click that link or not, but please don't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used to be able to set the status bar message using javascript, but you can not do that reliably anymore. This is most probably because the browser wants to protect the user. Instead of trying to hide the URL, perhaps you should work on a "redirect-URL" that looks reliable and that makes it obvious to the user both that it is a redirect-URL and where it is going. For example this kind of URL would both make me aware of where I am going and that my access is going to be recorded:

tracker.my-ad-network.com/stacktrace.com/ad/568

Instead of something like this (that would not make me feel safe):

dashj2.gggfbad.com/index.php?aid=1232808432&ref=123432.

And as noted above, start accepting serious attempt to help you or people will simply stop :)

Piotr

Comment: Yes. it is already there. still i dont want to show tracker.my-ad-network... .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new data attribute so your code would look something like this:

```
<a href="/link/user/will/end/up/on" data-redir="tracking/link">link text</a>
```

Then in  your JS, if you're using jQuery for example:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var loc = $(this).data('redir');
    window.location = loc;
}
```

Not too hacky for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: let me try that and will be back.